# How to query Realm on background Thread using RxJava2

Tags: android, multithreading, realm, kotlin, rx-java

I want to read/query and transform Realm data on a background thread using RxJava2. Here is an Observable:

```
fun getAllPlayers(): Observable<List<Player>> {
    return Observable.create { emitter ->
        val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        val players = realm.where(Player::class.java).findAll()

        val listener = RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Player>> { players ->
            if (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                emitter.onNext(realm.copyFromRealm(players))
            }
        }

        emitter.setDisposable(Disposables.fromRunnable(Runnable {
            players.removeChangeListener(listener)
            realm.close()
        }))

        players.addChangeListener(listener)
        emitter.onNext(realm.copyFromRealm(players))
    }
}
```

If I try to apply the following to the observable:

```
getAllPlayers()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

I get this dreadful error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Listeners cannot be used on the current thread. Realm cannot be automatically updated on a thread without a looper.

Ok, let's create a Scheduler with a Looper:

```
fun createSubscribeOnScheduler(): Scheduler {
    val t = HandlerThread("worker")
    if (!t.isAlive())
        t.start()
    return AndroidSchedulers.from(t.looper)
}
```

We can use it as such:

```
val subscribeOnScheduler = createSubscribeOnScheduler()
getAllPlayers()
    .subscribeOn(subscribeOnScheduler)
    .unsubscribeOn(subscribeOnScheduler)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Now everything works just fine. However, who is going to kill that HandlerThread? What if `getAllPlayer()` is called simultaneously from multiple places? Do other (and better) solutions exist for querying Realm on a background thread using RxJava2?

Comment: It seems to me that you're on the right path. Just create the HandlerThread and AndroidScheduler just once (a.k.a. singleton) and keep re-using them for every observable on Realm. No need to close the thread.

Comment: Thanks, @Budius! Any idea if the suggested approach will allow me to execute multiple queries simultaneously (that is, in parallel)?

Comment: Make sure you use the async query api (`findAllAsync()` and co) for background looper threads. You can get weird race conditions using the synchronous api for some reason.

Comment: why `AndroidScheduler `created from `HandlerThread` should be as a singleton? I think whenever you use your schedule it always will be using the same thread what has used at the first usage. What if you have chain of request that are executed in different threads. is that means realm request (save, loading data etc) doesn't matter on which thread is executed?